# How to write a CaesarCipher without any for loops?

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

The program has to just encrypt the input word for the input key and not decrypt. There is code available online but all are using for loops. My professor told me I shouldn't use any.

Comment: what have you tried so far. On this site you won't find anybody who'll just provide you the code you need for your homework.

Comment: You will still need to iterate over the chars to encrypt

Comment: no for loop, search for recursion then.

Comment: You can do it with a `while` loop. The code is just a bit uglier.

Comment: Yeah you can do each substitution easily enough without any loops, but you are going to need to loop through the thing once per input letter almost no matter what.  Unless you inline the substitution code 5 times in a row and throw an error if the input word is not exactly 5 letters long, or something of that sort which is horrible programming.

Comment: You could also use java 8 stream api ("abc".chars().map(c -> ...))